# Jboss 7.1.1 , JDK1.6 and drools 5.4 final, Exception in the logs

Tags: jboss, drools

I am using Jboss 7.1.1 , JDK1.6 and drools 5.4 final version .

Keep getting exception in jboss logs while creating KnowledgeBuilder object. The drools jar are located external to war file and path has been specified in module.xml. Any ideas how to resolve this or What is causing this? Please let me know,

Thanks

-J

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl

Looks like the drools-core or drools-compiler jar is not on the classpath.